# Is it legal to modify `module.paths` in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require, commonjs

[Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_module_paths) are not very helpful, since they do not clarify is this property mutable or not.

It is important, because changing this variable actually leads to changes in the behavior of `require` function.
So it would be good if someone make it clear what kind of usage this property supports and intended to.

Basically, the following code works just fine:

```js
const path = require(`path`);

// adding path to `lol` directory, which contains `kek.js` file
module.paths.unshift( path.join(__dirname, `lol`) );

// require works, despite `kek` is not inside of any of `node_modules` directories
const kek = require("kek");

// kek
console.log(kek);
```

But should it work at all?
It hard to say from the docs.

Please, advise. Thanks.

Comment: It might be easiest to approach this by determining what the default variable type is when undeclared within the compiler itself.

Comment: I wouldn't do this unless you really need to because it will be very obscure.